# WAMP icon suddenly orange

Tags: server, wampserver, wamp

**I've been running WAMP for like 6 months+** with Skype (also did the Skype port change just for the sake of it) - **with no problems**.

Today I open up WAMP -> get a green icon ->I then add an "alias" to the "alias directory" (already have 10+ other aliases working) -> **WAMP restarts and stay on the ORANGE icon** :/

- I've installed nothing new on my computer for ages
- I haven't changed any settings for ages
- I've restarted the computer several times
- I've closed down Skype and opened WAMP afterwards

I checked both MySQL + Apache log, but don't seem to see any errors.

```
MYSQL
--------------------
131205 16:42:07 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

131205 16:42:07 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
131205 16:42:07  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
131205 16:42:08  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 54497659
131205 16:42:08 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

131205 16:42:13 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131205 16:42:13 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131205 16:42:13 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
131205 16:42:13 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
131205 16:42:13 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131205 16:42:13 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131205 16:42:13 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
131205 16:42:13  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131205 16:42:14 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 54497659
131205 16:42:14 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
131205 16:42:14 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
131205 16:42:14 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
131205 16:42:14 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
131205 16:42:14 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
131205 16:42:14 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
--------------------


APACHE ERROR LOG
--------------------
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [warn] pid file C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) PHP/5.3.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [notice] Server built: May 13 2012 19:41:17
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 9272
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [notice] Child 9272: Child process is running
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [notice] Child 9272: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [notice] Child 9272: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [notice] Child 9272: Starting thread to listen on port 100.
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [notice] Child 9272: Starting thread to listen on port 100.
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [notice] Child 9272: Starting thread to listen on port 100.
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [notice] Child 9272: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Dec 05 15:30:52 2013] [notice] Child 9272: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Dec 05 15:31:12 2013] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Thu Dec 05 15:31:12 2013] [notice] Child 9272: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Thu Dec 05 15:31:13 2013] [notice] Child 9272: Released the start mutex
[Thu Dec 05 15:31:14 2013] [notice] Child 9272: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu Dec 05 15:31:14 2013] [notice] Child 9272: Child process is exiting
[Thu Dec 05 15:31:14 2013] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
--------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the WAMP icon turns orange it means that it wasn't able to start up properly.

You say that you made a configuration change just before it turned orange.  It sounds like you broke the Apache configuration when you added the alias.  Although it is likely not to be the same exact problem you have [here is a report from somebody who fixed the orange WAMP icon with a minor fix to their Apache configuration](http://damselflydevelopment.com/2012/11/wamp-wont-start-stuck-on-orange-logo/).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713001/where-can-i-find-the-wamp-error-log), WAMP writes its log files into `C:\wamp\logs`.  Look at `error.log` in that directory.  If Apache is having trouble starting up, it will write information about the problem into that location.

Comment: Hi Stephen,

Youre completely right - it was an issue with the alias itself. I was just so tired in my head that I didnt notice it easlier, but the path was not 100% correct = apache saw it as not existing = failed to start up. It's all good now with the correct alias path - figure it would be right to accept your answer? Atleast that's what made me look at the alias more throughoutly again.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the alias you just added.

Add the alias back in manually, ideally by copying one you already have that you know works, then carefully modifying it accordingly. Be careful with spaces.

As the accepted answer mentions, the new alias is almost certainly the problem. Only reason for adding a separate answer is that in my experience of this exact same scenario the error.log isn't  going to help much.

And it's quicker just to kill the faulty alias and start again.